# Orocommerce Akeneo display Categories in Navbar

Tags: navigation, categories, orocommerce, akeneo

I have a PIM Akeneo connect to orocommerce (community edition for both - Akeneo 5.0 and Oro 4.2).
I can import my Categories from Akeneo to Orocommerce Master Catalogue.

As you can see my "Catalogue Principal" is exported on Orocommerce but it's a child of "All products"

[image]

**How could I do for merge "Catalogue Principal" and "All products" or another Solution for display child of "Catalogue Principal" in my nav bar ?**

By the way using Webcatalogue is not a solution for me cause I want to keep the default nav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `Oro\Bundle\CatalogBundle\Layout\DataProvider\CategoryProvider::getRootCategory()` method to return the ID of the "Catalogue Principal" category.

Alternatively, you can try to unse the root category for the transport. It's not configurable from UI, but you can write a migration: https://github.com/oroinc/OroAkeneoBundle/blob/0e70f4035ddf7e2009e8495601f8655ebf104fba/ImportExport/DataConverter/CategoryDataConverter.php#L86.